# Using two key for displaying data from contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, cpp-ethereum

i can't found any idea how to get data with two keys. One key "address", second key is "IsCollect"

My mapping:

```
    mapping(address => Player) public users;
```

struct table:

```
    struct Deposit {
        uint256 depositTime;
        uint256 amount;
        bool IsCollect;
    }
```

Insert:

```
 users[addr].deposits.push(Deposit(now, amount,false);
```

Retrieving:

```
function getPlayerDepositHistory(address addr) public view returns (uint256[] memory, uint256[] memory, bool[] memory) {
        DepositHistory[] memory invests = users[addr].deposithistory;
        uint256[] memory baseTimes = new uint256[](invests.length);
        uint256[] memory values = new uint256[](invests.length);
        bool[] memory IsCollect = new bool[](invests.length);    

        uint256 i = 0;
        uint256 timeSpent = 0;
        while (i < invests.length){
            DepositHistory memory invest = invests[i];
            
    //        if (invest.IsCollect=false)
      //      {
                
        if (invest.lastDepositTime < invest.depositTime.add(PERIOD[0])){
                    uint256 remainedTime = PERIOD[0].sub(invest.lastDepositTime.sub(invest.depositTime));
                    if (remainedTime > 0){    
                    timeSpent=now.sub(invest.lastDepositTime);
                    if (remainedTime <= timeSpent){
                        timeSpent = remainedTime;
                        }
                    }
                   
            baseTimes[i] = invest.depositTime;
            values[i] = invest.amount;
            IsCollect[i] = invest.IsCollect;
        
                    
        }i++;  
           // }
        }
        

        return (baseTimes, values, IsCollect);
}
```

I need second key IsCollect=true. If is true I need to display only data which is True

I have tried to use:
if (invest.IsCollect=false)
{

}

Its not works.

Appreciate for help.

Comment: Did `if (invest.IsCollect=false)` even compile for you???

Comment: yes compile, but after want to try still I get false and true

Comment: I have false and I use                             if (invest.IsCollect=true)
                   {  in my row I goot [bool]: true, so update result instead of not display.

Comment: To begin with, use `=` for assignment and `==` for comparison (or I guess, if you didn't get that from my comment above, then start by learning the basics of the language first).

Comment: hi, yes I forgot that but before send question I added "==" and the problem is not. If change instead of bool, like uint256 works... but if not exists I got: "class org.tron.core.vm.program.Program$OutOfTimeException : CPU timeout for 'MSTORE' operation executing"

Is this ok if not exists result I got this?

Comment: @dkr1985 Can you share the code to compile? It is missing large chunks and it is not enough to test.

Comment: Hi Ismael I resolved with js calling where is false display false, where is true display true. thanks for the help anyway